# SwiftUI - call a func in a View from outside

Tags: swiftui

is it possible to call a func of a View from outside.
I tried like this, but had no success.

```
@main
struct CallFromOutsideApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      SubView()
      Button("Call alterX in ContentView"){
        // How to call alterX in SubView????
      }
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

struct SubView: View {
  @State var x = "Status A"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Status: \(x)")
      Button("Call alterX in SubView"){ alterX()
      }
    }
    .padding()
  }
  
  func alterX(){
    x = "Status B"
  }
}
```

Comment: Next should be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940114/14733292

Comment: You try to bring interactive nature to SwiftUI reactive world. It does not work in that way. The most common schema is *Action > ViewModel > View*, ie. some action changes some view model and dependent view (observing that view model) reacts and updates corresponding parts. View model is any external dynamic source of truth.

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT

You shouldn't control `SubView`'s `@State` from `ContentView`. Instead, put the `@State` in `ContentView` and pass it to a `@Binding` in `SubView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var x = "Status A"
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            SubView(x: $x) /// pass in the binding
            
            Button("Alter X in ContentView"){
                x = "Status B"
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var x: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Status: \(x)")
            Button("Alter X in SubView") {
                x = "Status B"
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

---

You could store `SubView` in a property. Like

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let subView = SubView()
  var body: some View {
    VStack{

      subView /// like this

      Button("Call alterX in ContentView"){
        subView.alterX() /// call it
      }
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

struct SubView: View {
  @State var x = "Status A"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Status: \(x)")
      Button("Call alterX in SubView"){ alterX()
      }
    }
    .padding()
  }
  
  func alterX(){
    x = "Status B"
  }
}
```

Comment: thnx - interesting: in the second approach "alterX" gets called but the state change isn't reflected in the UI